# Where can I find legendary crafting materials?

Tags: diablo-iii

My boulder barbarian would love some Reaper's Wraps but they require [Reaper's Fear](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/reapers-fear). I've found various other crafting plans that require legendary materials.

Where can I find Reaper's Fear and other legendary crafting materials? Are there places to farm these materials or is it all luck of the draw?

Comment: As far as I can see, You can only pray to the RNG gods. Not 100% sure though.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

This [Diablo 3 Craftables Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AvsZ08eb5x05dFJXNXFBdHFWR09sX2VkMDVXU0xiSVE&usp=drive_web#gid=0) is particularly helpful when trying to figure out if you are in an area with a possible legendary crafting material drop.

Here is the same list in not so sortable form:

**Legendary Crafting Materials:**

- [Adventurer's Journal](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/adventurers-journal)

  - **Found in**: Acts 1-4 - Various World Objects
  - **Used For**: [Pender's Purchase](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/penders-purchase)
- [Angelic Shard](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/angelic-shard)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 4 - The Great Span: Izaul
    - Act 4 - Multiple Areas: Corrupted Angel
    - Act 4 - The Silver Spire Level 1: Pyres the Damned
    - Act 5 - Pandemonium Fortress Level 2: Celic
  - **Used For**: [Hallowed Protectors Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/hallowed-barricade)
- [Behistun Rune](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/behistun-rune)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Leoric's Manor: Krailen the Wicked
    - Act 2 - Road to Alcarnus: Yeth
  - **Used For**: [Mark of the Magi](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/mark-of-the-magi)
- [Bloody Pincer](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/bloody-pincer)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - Tower of the Damned Level 2: Crabbs
    - Act 3 - The Core of Arreat: Scorpitox
    - Act 5 - Ruins of Corvus: Balata
  - **Used For**: [Demon Claw](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/demon-claw)
- [Born's Key](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/borns-key)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Cemetary of the Forsaken: Lucious the Depraved
    - Act 1 - Defiled Crypt: Digger O'Dell
    - Act 1 - Defiled Crypt: Dataminer
    - Act 1 - Defiled Crypt: John Gorham
  - **Used For**: [Born's Command Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/borns-frozen-soul)
- [Captured Nightmare](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/captured-nightmare)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 4 - The Silver Spire Level 2: Grimnight the Soulless
    - Act 4 - The Silver Spire Level 1/2: Terror Demons and Enslaved Nightmares
  - **Used For**: [Night's Reaping](http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/nights-reaping)
- [Captured Soul](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/captured-soul)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - The Keep Depths Level 2: Aloysius the Ghastly
  - **Used For**: [Lai Yui's Persuader](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/lai-yuis-persuader)
- [Cartographer's Toolkit](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/cartographers-toolkit)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Festering Woods: Grimsmack
    - Act 1 - Festering Woods: Enkidu (Ancient War Event)
    - Act 3 - Rakkis Crossing: Lavarinth (Blaze of Glory Event)
    - Act 3 - Tower of the Damned: Gholash
  - **Used For**: [Board Walker's](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/board-walkers)
- [Cultist Blood](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/cultist-blood)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Halls of Agony: Cultist Grant Inquisitor
    - Act 2 - Alcarnus: High Cultist Murdos
    - Act 2 - Alcarnus: Jhorum the Cleric
  - **Used For**: [Blood Magic Dagger](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/bloodmagic-edge)
- [Defiled Doll](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/defiled-doll)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 4 - The Silver Spire Level 1: Kysindra the Wretched
    - Act 5 - House of Deep Sorrow: Lady Victoria (Event Spawn)
  - **Used For**: [Spite](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/spite)
- [Demon Skin](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/demon-skin)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - The Core of Arreat: Axgore the Cleaver
    - Act 3 - Tower of the Damned Level 1: Haxxor
    - Act 4 - Gardens of Hope Tier 1: Khatun
    - Act 4 - Gardens of Hope Tier 2: Razorclaw
  - **Used For**: [Demon's Hide Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/demons-animus)
- [Element of Celerity](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/element-of-celerity)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - The Weeping Hollow: Mange
    - Act 1 - Fields of Misery: Burrow Bile (The Forlorn Farm Event)
    - Act 1 - Fields of Misery: Dreadclaw the Leaper
    - Act 1 - The Lost Mine (Fields of Misery): Shanabi (Precious Ores Event)
    - Act 1 - Watch Tower Level 2: Armorer's Bane (Scavenged Scabbard Event)
      **Used For**: [Fleeting Strap](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/fleeting-strap)
- [Essence of the Twin Seas](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/essence-of-the-twin-seas)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 2 - Black Canyon Mines: Razormouth
    - Act 2 - Sewers of Caldeum: Moontooth Dreadshark
  - **Used For**: [Captain Crimson's Trimmings Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/captain-crimsons-silk-girdle)
- [Eternal Power Capsule](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/eternal-power-capsule)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Whimsyshire: Evil Oliver
  - **Used For**: [Arcane Barb](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/arcane-barb)
- [Eyes of the Dead](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/eyes-of-the-dead)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Leoric's Passage: Headcleaver (Quest Spawn)
    - Act 1 - Cathedral Level 2: Merrium Skullthorn
  - **Used For**: [War of the Dead](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/war-of-the-dead)
- [Frozen Blood](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/frozen-blood)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - Caverns of Frost: Chiltara
  - **Used For**: [Utar's Roar](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/utars-roar)
- [Glowing Ore](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/glowing-ore)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 5 - Battlefields of Eternity: Sartor
    - Act 5 - Pandemonium Fortress: Soul Scavenger (The Souls of Angels Event)
  - **Used For**: [Cosmic Strand](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/cosmic-strand)
- [Griswold's Scribblings](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/griswolds-scribblings)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Cathedral: Bookshelves
    - Act 1 - Cemetery of the Forsaken: Gravedigger's Corpse
    - Act 1 - Festering Woods: Enmerkar (Last Stand of the Ancients Event)
    - Act 1 - Wortham Chapel: Bookshelves
    - Act 2 - Khasim Outpost: Cain's Lost Satchel
    - Act 2 - Khasim Outpost: Imperial Guard Supplies
    - Act 2 - Zoltun Kulle Dungeons: Bookshelves
    - Act 3 - Skycrown Battlements: Morgan's Satchel
    - Act 3 - The Keep Depths: Lore Objects
    - Act 4 - Multiple Areas: Angel Archives
  - **Used For**: [Griswold's Perfection](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/griswolds-perfection)
- [Hilt of the Silver Wolf](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/hilt-of-the-silver-wolf)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - Arreat Crater Level 1: Growlfang
    - Act 3 - Tower of the Damned Level 1: Gnawbone
  - **Used For**: [Golden Scourge](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/golden-scourge)
- [Human Cartilage](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/human-cartilage)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Cathedral Level 2: Cudgelarm
    - Act 1 - Defiled Crypt Level 2: Mangelmaw
  - **Used For**: [Wall of Man](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/wall-of-man)
- [Iron Wolves Doctrine](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/iron-wolves-doctrine)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 2 - Dahlgur Oasis: Ssthrass
  - **Used For**: [Asheara's Vestment Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/ashearas-custodian)
- [Living Flame](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/living-flame)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 4 - The Silver Spire Level 2: Sao'Thall
    - Act 4 - The Silver Spire Level 2: Rhau'Kye
    - Act 4 - Radiant Chapel: Malfeas the Abhorrent
  - **Used For**: [Cinder Switch](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/cinder-switch)
- [Lyekurn's Diary](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/lyekurns-diary)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - The Heart of Sin: Azmodan
  - **Used For**: [Corruption](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/corruption)
- [Maghda's Tormented Soul](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/maghdas-tormented-soul)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 2 - Lair of the Witch: Maghda
  - **Used For**: [Cain's Destiny Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/cains-habit)
- [Mystical Source](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/mystical-source)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1: Whimsyshire: Midnight Sparkle
    - Act 1: Whimsyshire: Nightmarity
    - Act 1: Whimsyshire: Team Unicorn
    - Act 1: Whimsyshire: Creampuff
  - **Used For**: [Sage's Journey Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/sages-apogee)
- [Phial of Weakness](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/phial-of-weakness)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - The Battlefields: Deadgrasp
    - Act 3 - The Battlefields: Handible (Triage Event)
  - **Used For**: [Atrophy](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/atrophy)
- [Quaking Vial](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/quaking-vial)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 4 - Hellrift Level 1: Sledge
    - Act 4 - Hellrift Level 2: Hammermash
  - **Used For**: [Sunder](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/sunder)
- [Reaper's Fear](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/reapers-fear)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 5 - Heart of the Fortress: Maltheal
  - **Used For**: [Reaper's Wraps](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/reapers-wraps)
- [Rydraelm Tome](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/rydraelm-tome)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 2 - The Lost Caravan (Stinging Winds): Beyatt
    - Act 2 - Daulguhr Oasis: Ashangu
  - **Used For**: [Mantle of the Rydraelm](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/mantle-of-the-rydraelm)
- [Shard of the Ensteig Plate](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/shard-of-entsteig-plate)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Defiled Crypt: Lord Dunhyld (The Matriarch of Bones Event)
    - Act 1 - Festering Woods: Feklar's Ghost
    - Act 1 - Festering Woods: Hawthorne Gable
    - Act 2 - Sewers of Caldeum: Shade of Nar Gulle
    - Act 2 - Unknown Depths: The Archivist (Event Spawn)
    - Act 2 - Tomb of Khan Dakab: Spirit of Khan Dakab (Event Spawn)
  - **Used For**: [Aughild's Authority Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/aughilds-power)
- [Shattered Core](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/shattered-core)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 2 - Forgotten Ruins: Ancient Guardian
    - Act 2 - Unknown Depths: Rockgut
    - Act 2 - Realm of Shadow: Thrum
  - **Used For**: [Devastator](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/devastator)
- [Shimmering Quill](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/shimmering-quill)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Dank Cellar: Sarkoth
    - Act 1 - Musty Cellar: Gorathra
    - Act 3 - Keep Depths Level 1: Thornback
  - **Used For**: [Unbound Bolt](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/unbound-bolt)
- [Shuddering Demon Bone](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/shuddering-demon-bone)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 4 - Gardens of Hope Tier 2: Koa' Ahn
    - Act 4 - Gardens of Hope Tier 2: Oah' Tash
  - **Used For**: [Archfiend Arrows](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/archfiend-arrows)
- [Skeleton's Dice](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/skelons-dice)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 4 - Gardens of Hope Tier 1: Torchlighter
    - Act 5 -  Battlefields of Eternity: Emikdeva
    - Act 5 -  Battlefields of Eternity: Korchoroth
  - **Used For**: [Skeleton's Deceit](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/skelons-deceit)
- [Skull of Raylend](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/skull-of-raylend)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - The Keep Depths Level 2: Bholen
    - Act 3 - Rakki's Crossing: Garganug
    - Act 3 - Core of Arreat: Gorog the Bruiser
  - **Used For**: [The Helm of Rule](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/the-helm-of-rule)
  - [Sydyru Bone](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/sydyru-bone)
  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Cathedral Level 1: Gildewing
    - Act 1 - Cathedral Level 1: Firestarter
    - Act 1 - Fields of Misery: Sicklefang (Carrion Farm Event)
    - Act 3 - Unknown Depths: Hellscream
  - **Used For**: [Sydyru Crust](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/sydryu-crust)
- [Symbol of the Guardian Brotherhood](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/symbol-of-the-guardian-brotherhood)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 3 - Skycrown Battlements: Thromp the Breaker
    - Act 3 - Stonefort: Bashface the Truncheon
    - Act 3 - Stonefort: Dragus (Waiting for Reinforcements Event)
    - Act 3 - The Keep Depths Level 2: The Crusher
    - Act 3 - Rakkis Crossing: Busaw (Crazy Climber Event)
  - **Used For**: [Guardian's Jeopardy Set](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/guardians-aversion)
- [Torn Soul](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/torn-soul)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Southern Highlands: Lorzak the Powerful
    - Act 1 - Southern Highlands: Skehlinrath
  - **Used For**: [Living Umbral Oath](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/living-umbral-oath)
- [Urn of Quickening](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/urn-of-quickening)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 2 - Stinging Winds: Erach
    - Act 3 - Caverns of Frost Level 2: Chiltara
    - Act 3 - Caverns of Frost Level 2: Scathach the Savage
    - Act 3 - Icefall Caves: Zelusa the Grasping
    - Act 5 - Heart of the Fortress: Malthael (* May be a bug)
  - **Used For**: [Kethryes' Splint](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/kethryes-splint)
- [White Oak Splinter](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/white-oak-splinter)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Secluded Grove (Fields of Misery): The Old Man
  - **Used For**: [Rozpedin's Force](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/rozpedins-force)
- [Wooden Stake](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/wooden-stake)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - Cathedral Level 4: Killian Damort
    - Act 3 - The Keep Depths Level 3: Belagg Pierceflesh
  - **Used For**: [Blitzbolter](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/blitzbolter)
- [Woven Plate](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/woven-plate)

  - **Found in**:

    - Act 1 - The Cathedral Level 4: Captain Cage
    - Act 1 - The Festering Woods: Enmerkar (The Last Stand of the Ancients Event)
    - Act 3 - The Keep Depths Level 1: Captain Donn Adams
  - **Used For**: [Piro Marella](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/piro-marella)

---

**Infernal Machine Crafting Components:**

- [Key of Bones](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/key-of-bones)

  - **Found in**:

    - [Various Acts - Keywardens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162148/where-do-i-find-the-ros-keys)
  - **Used For**:

    - [Infernal Machine of Bones](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-bones)
    - [Infernal Machine of Evil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-evil)
    - [Infernal Machine of Gluttony](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-gluttony)
    - [Infernal Machine of War](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-war)
- [Key of Evil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/key-of-evil)

  - **Found in**:

    - [Various Acts - Keywardens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162148/where-do-i-find-the-ros-keys)
  - **Used For**:

    - [Infernal Machine of Bones](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-bones)
    - [Infernal Machine of Evil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-evil)
    - [Infernal Machine of Gluttony](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-gluttony)
    - [Infernal Machine of War](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-war)
- [Key of Gluttony](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/key-of-gluttony)

  - **Found in**:

    - [Various Acts - Keywardens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162148/where-do-i-find-the-ros-keys)
  - **Used For**:

    - [Infernal Machine of Bones](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-bones)
    - [Infernal Machine of Evil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-evil)
    - [Infernal Machine of Gluttony](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-gluttony)
    - [Infernal Machine of War](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-war)
- [Key of War](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/item/key-of-war)

  - **Found in**:

    - [Various Acts - Keywardens](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/162148/where-do-i-find-the-ros-keys)
  - **Used For**:

    - [Infernal Machine of Bones](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-bones)
    - [Infernal Machine of Evil](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-evil)
    - [Infernal Machine of Gluttony](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-gluttony)
    - [Infernal Machine of War](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/artisan/blacksmith/recipe/infernal-machine-of-war)

[Source](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/83094-guide-legendary-crafting-materials-drop-locations) for the various locations

Answer (score 12):

According to [this page on Diablofans](http://www.diablofans.com/forums/diablo-iii-general-forums/diablo-iii-general-discussion/83094-guide-legendary-crafting-materials-drop-locations), only Malthael himself drops this specific crafting material:

> - Acquired from: Act V, Heart of the Fortress, Malthael
> - Where to farm: Act V, Heart of the Fortress
> - Used for: Reaper's Wraps, Wrists, Health globes restore 25–30% of your primary resource, 5 random magic properties (as opposed to the 8
>     properties according to Battle.net)
> - Note: Malthael also drops the Recipe for Reaper's Wraps.

This sounds pretty plausible to me as I also got the plan from him (which seems to be a guaranteed drop).