# Where do I find the RoS Keys?

Tags: diablo-iii

I recently found the level 12 plan for The Infernal Machine in Reaper of Souls. Where do I find the components to make one of them?

It requires the following keys to craft:

- Key of Bones
- Key of Gluttony
- Key of War
- Key of Evil

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to be level 70 and in a game on difficulty Torment 1 or higher.
The keywarden spawns in adventuremode aswell.

This are the new Keys in RoS:

- Key of Bones - Act I, Fields of Misery
- Key of Gluttony - Act II, Dahlgur Oasis
- Key of War - Act III, Stonefort
- Key of Evil - Act IV, Silver Spire Level 1

Sidenote: If you do not all ready have the infernal machine plans, the first keywarden you kill will drop the plans and still has a chance to drop a key.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://diablo.blizzplanet.com/blog/comments/infernal-machine-level-70-guide) and [this](http://www.diabloiiigold.com/news-459--diablo-3-ros-hellfire-ring-faqs.html) pages, the keys are still being dropped by *Keywardens* as in pre-2.0 patches.

The only 2 differences is that:

- now you also need to farm *Nekarat* in Act IV for the key
- *Keywardens* now have chance of dropping a key of other keywardens(my interpretation: all *Keywardens* drop all keys)

These keys only drop at level 70. Before that you will probably get "normal"(old) keys.

Comment: I will note that I got the plan from the key warden in act 2 in torment 1. So the first source seems wrong on where you can get the machine plans.

Comment: Machine plan drops instead of your first key from any of the keywardens. Once you have taught it to your blacksmith they only drop keys.