# What is a quick way to farm demon skin on lvl 70?

Tags: diablo-iii

I found a set plan today, which requires Demon Skin as an ingredient. I was trying to look it up on Battle.Net, but there seems to be no page for that material and most stuff I found on the internet was outdated. So what is the best and quickest way to farm Demon Skins? Does it drop in a specific place or is it just random? I never seen that one at all.

[image: Screenshot of ingredient]

Comment: We've got this question: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/161809/where-can-i-find-legendary-crafting-materials, that answers where to find it, but I'm not sure if we really need separate questions about how best to farm them.

Comment: As stated by Frank, once you know the location, go in adventure mode and clear all the area where you can fin the mob that drop the demon skin > repeat til you got it. OR find the fastest location to kill on of the mob and repeat. However a Bluz post on the forum stated recently that crafting material should havea higher drop rate and they intend to buff it in a near hotfix so I wouldn't start farming those now.

Comment: btw bliz has acknowledged that the drop rate for crafting mats suck right now and they plan to bump it at some point.  Not sure if you want to hold off until then.

Comment: With this specific material there are many ways to farm it, I would not flag it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Legendary materials are usually found as drops off super-unique monsters (the ones with the purple names). Demon Skins can be found on the following monsters:

- Axgore the Cleaver (Phase Beast): Act III, The Core of Arreat
- Haxxor (Phase Beast): Act III, Tower of the Damned Level 1
- Khatun (Sky Terror): Act IV, Gardens of Hope Tier 1
- Razorclaw (Sky Terror): Act IV, Gardens of Hope Tier 2 (spawns during the quest, The Light of Hope).

Because they drop off super-unique monsters, you won't be guaranteed a chance at the drop when you create a new game as the monster may not even spawn! Be sure to pay attention to bounties that target these monsters, as the bounty guarantees that the monster will spawn.

Comment: The bounty tip is especially good. +1

Comment: Yep the bounty tip is key, I did this and had Haxxor come up 2x in only 4 resets. After 2.04 crafting mat drop rate increase I got the demon skin in both of those kills :)

Comment: A good option is to farm Razorclaw through the "Light of hope quest", in campaign he is a guaranteed spawn.

Comment: I can confirm that 90% of the time the bounty method will be faster. If you were to continually farm Axgore by clearing the Core of Arreat, compared with farming the bounties...you will get your Demon Skin's a lot faster by continually reloading and checking for bounties.